# Оптимизация сайта под разные разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css

Недавно был заказ сверстать сайт, где на главной странице распологались герои журнала. И эти герои и есть навигационное меню. Соответственно вырезал картинку и загнал ее в линк так:

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/picture.jpg" /></a>
```

Все выровнил, как пологается т.е сделал прилепающий футер и если высота экрана не меньше 800 пикселей, то масштабирование происходит на ура, но переходим на ноутбук диагональ которого 15. Появляется скролл-принял решение уменьшить картинки и подгружать их через CSS3

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px)
```

и тут должен идти другой стиль для данного разрешения.

**Вопрос**: как мне в CSS можно в тэг `<img>`  загнуть другую картинку, ту, что поменьше масштабом? (кажется, это адаптивная верстка называется)

Comment: Пробовали читать про адаптивную верстку в ИНТЕРНЕТЕ?

Comment: конечно, и причем я ее использую. У меня конкретный вопрос ведь... как в тег <img> загнать другую картинку через CSS если высота экрана стала меньше чем 800 пикселей! Без скриптов!

Comment: В бутстраповском мануале есть все для понимания данного вопроса.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: >был заказ

Ну так и сделай это заказ. Или оплати работу.

Comment: а что если всех "героев" разместить в дивах 

.horovodov {
width:300px;height:500px;
float:left;
background:url('images/norm.png');
}

далее

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {

.horovodov {
width:150px;height:250px;
background:url('images/small.png');
}
}

Comment: замучаешься выравнивать, нет разве ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ага, ну да:

> Applies to::before and ::afterpseudo-elements

Вот так работает везде (ie 9+, ff 19, chrome 25)

```
<style>

.adaptive-image:after { content: url('image-def.jpg'); }

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .adaptive-image:after { content: url('image-800.jpg'); }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .adaptive-image:after { content: url('image-1024.jpg'); }
}

</style>
<div class="adaptive-image"></div>
```

Но тогда уж лучше `background` ставить.

Comment: то что можно подменить сам бекграунд это не проблема и это работает. но как я понял погуглив вчера, что самому тегу IMG его SRC заменить без скрипта просто не возможно. Придется переделать на бекграунд ссылке, а тег IMG удалить.

Comment: Я даже рад этому, ибо CSS — таблица **стилей**. Как по-мне, то даже псевдоэлементы :after и :before уже несколько выходят за рамки возложенной на CSS задачи, что только привносит путаницу.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

HTML

```
<a href="#"><img id="adaptive" src="img/picture.jpg" /></a>
```

CSS

```
#adaptive{
    content:url("img/small_picture.jpg");
}
```

[Подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content)

Comment: хорошо спасибо попробую результат сообщу позже )

Comment: нет к сожаление не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Используй HTMLscale и все картинки и щрифт на сайте будет подстраиваться под ширину экрана
[link text](http://www.cms-sd.ru/stati/javascript_i_jquery/htmlscale_mashtabirovanie_stranici_pod_shirinu_ekrana)

Answer (score 1):

Не надо пихать картинку с помощью тега, так трудно управлять им. Создай блок и истанови заливку картинкой. background-size: cover; попробуй для такого блока. Так же можешь попробовать с background-size свойство, на оно не везде используется background-repeat.